# Appending to string in bash

Tags: bash, string

I have a bash script.  It has a loop within, which builds a file-name.
I want to keep a list of file-names that are created.
It seems like it takes the file-name as something to execute, rather than as text.  I get xxx: command not found error on each append and command that is not found is the file name I want to append.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant lines of your script.

Comment: Please edit question, to show what you did, and what the result was. From what you have told us, we can tell you “something went wrong somewhere”.

Comment: consider using an array for this purpose, instead

Answer (score 1):

If your code does something like this in the loop:

```
STRING=$STRING/$COMPONENT
```

the error message makes me think you've got whitespace (space or tab characters) by the '=' character.  That is, do this:

```
STRING="$STRING/$COMPONENT"
```

Don't do this:

```
STRING  =  $STRING / $COMPONENT
```

Comment: It is tradition for only environment variables to be capitals.